# Outputting list to a "matrix" type format in python

Tags: python

```
my_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven']
```

Using python, I need list to be displayed as:

```
one, two, three
four, five, six
seven
```

I need it to be flexible, as the list will change frequently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the grouper [recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) from itertools:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Use like this:

```
for line in grouper(3, my_list):
    print ', '.join(filter(None, line))
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/IyoZt)

Answer (score 0):

```
def matprint(L, numcols):
    for i,item in enumerate(L):
        print item,
        if i and not (i+1)%numcols:
            print '\n',

>>> my_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven']
>>> matprint(my_list, 3)
one two three 
four five six 
seven
```